# Rewriting conditional expectation of a conditional expectation

Tags: conditional-expectation, bayes-theorem, expected-value

I'm attempting to derive an influence curve. I'm not necessarily looking for an answer, but guidance on how to tackle something that should be relatively straightforward (I think). I'm asked the following:

Rewrite the parameter mapping $\Psi^1(P) = E[E[Y | A=1, W] | A=0]$ so that you have $P(A=0) $ in the denominator and an integral expression in the numerator.

I'm thrown off by the embedded conditional expectation within conditional expectation. What might be relevant are the following:

$(W,A,Y) \sim P \in M $

$W=$ Vector of covariates

$A,Y =$ binary $(0,1)$

My initial guess was :

$\frac{\int f(W=w, A=1, Y=y)}{P(A=0)}$

Though, this seems forced

Comment: Rather than talking about undefined (and unnecessary) concepts (influence curve, parameter mapping) you should have been clear about the joint distribution of $A,W,Y$.

Comment: You could have just asked me to explain a part of my question better. The variables W,A,Y come from a distribution P(O) that is unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem looks very familiar! Consider path $P_e$ through the true distribution, $P$ along score, $S$, defined by the density $p_e(w,a,y) = p(w,a,y)(1+eS(w,a,y)) = p_{Y,e}(y |a,w)p_{A,e}(a|w)p_{W,e}(w)$, where S is the score function.  Consult Aad van der Vaart, Asymptotic Statistics, BTW, for more about this. It's an excellent resource and Mark van der Laan's Targeted Learning.  Now let's take a derivative at e = 0 of the parameter mapping along that path.  Once we write this derivative as a covariance with the score, the function next to the score in the covariance is your efficient influence curve for a non-parametric model, by the riesz representation theorem.

$\frac{d}{de}\biggr\vert_{e=0}\Psi(P_e) = \frac{d}{de}\biggr\vert_{e=0}\int y p_{Y,e}(y | a=1, w)p_{A|W,e}(a=0|w)p_{W,e}(w)/P_e(a=0)dv(y,w)$.  Just ignore $P_e(a=0)$ and use the delta method to incorporate that IC later, which is (I(A = 0) - P(A=0)).